# Calling startIntentSenderForResult from Fragment (Android Billing v3)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-billing

The new Android Billing v3 documentation and helper code uses `startIntentSenderForResult()` when launching a purchase flow. I want to start a purchase flow (and receive the result) from a `Fragment`.

For example the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-requests) suggests calling

```
startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
    1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
    Integer.valueOf(0));
```

and the [helper code](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html#Purchase) calls

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_GAS, 10001,   
    mPurchaseFinishedListener, "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
```

which calls `startIntentSenderForResult()`.

The problem is, calling `startIntentSenderForResult()` causes `onActivityResult()` to be called on the parent `Activity` rather than on the `Fragment` that it was called from (where the `IabHelper` resides).

I could receive the `onActivityResult()` in the parent `Activity` and then manually call the `onActivityResult()` on the `Fragment`, but is there a way to make a call to `startIntentSenderForResult()` from a `Fragment` that returns the result directly to that `Fragment`'s `onActivityResult()`?

Comment: any workaround for that issue? I'm facing the same problem here, can't find any solution other than the hacky ones below...

Answer (score 36):

I suggest two solutions:

1.) Put the IabHelper mHelper on the activity and call the IabHelper from the fragment.

Something like:

To use this solution, Declare IabHelper as public in the activity and use a method to call the launcher from the Fragment.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    public IabHelper mHelper

    public purchaseLauncher(){

    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_GAS, 10001,   
         mPurchaseFinishedListener, "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");

   }

    /*The finished, query and consume listeners should also be implemented in here*/
}

public class FragmentActivity extends Fragment{

      MyActivity myAct = (MyActivity) getActivity();

      myAct.purchaseLauncher();

}
```

2.) In onActivityResult, call the appropriate fragment that contains the IabHelper object. Appropriate fragment can have an access method to the helper object.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data)    
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("YourTag");       
    if (fragment != null)
    {
        ((MyFragmentWithIabHelper)fragment).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am currently doing the second method, however I would rather my activity not know about the inner workings of the fragment and require plumbing in order for it to work. Right now the activity is simply a container for different billing fragments. Which fragment is used is based on which billing implementation I'm building for (e.g. Google Play, Samsung Apps).

Comment: It would be nice if there were a way for the result to automatically be directed to the fragment's `onActivityResult()`. Akin to calling `startActivityForResult()` from a fragment rather than calling `getActivity().startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: @ashughes it will be automatically directed if you call Fragment.startActivityForResult, look - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#FragmentActivity.onActivityResult%28int%2Cint%2Candroid.content.Intent%29

Comment: @RogerAlien correct, but `Fragment.startActivityForResult` is not being used, but rather `startIntentSenderForResult()` which does not mask the request code so that it is forwarded to the appropriate fragment.

Comment: If you invoked IAP through a fragment added to a child fragment manager, be sure to obtain the FragmentManager from the parent fragment through `getChildFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Used 1st method with ListFragment. Also fixed issue with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130044/android-billing-exception

Comment: How to do it for `startIntentSenderForResult` ?

Comment: Excellent Answer.

Answer (score 9):

1) You should modify your resultCode (RC_REQUEST) to put fragment index to it.

```
int rc_reqest = RC_REQUEST +  ((getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().indexOf(this)+1)<<16)  ;      
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(getActivity(), sku, rc_reqest ,mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

2) in IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(...)

```
change mRequestCode = requestCode
```

to

```
mRequestCode = requestCode&0xffff;
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this with normal "fragmentManager"? getActivity().getFragmentManager()...?... getFragment(?,?)

Comment: This seems to solve the problem. Should be the accepted answer. Don't forget to add `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` to `onActivityResult` in your activity.

Comment: Unfortunately, newer libraries do not allow this solution any more, complaining about: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode`

Comment: This solution uses the framework code that delegates results to fragments. Since this is not a public API, you can't rely on it working across all current and future versions.

Answer (score 4):

From SDK 24 and above, there is a [startIntentSenderForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#startIntentSenderForResult(android.content.IntentSender,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) method available in support Fragment also, which works as intended. 
Note that there is an additional Bundle parameter, which can be passed as null. Thus, final code will be:

```
startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
    1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
    Integer.valueOf(0), null);
```

Of course, for API 23 and below, we will still need to use the tricks described in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding LEO's very helpful 2nd solution above:

If Google ever fixes the issue with startIntentSenderForResult and it now correctly routes the onActivityResult call to the fragment, then this solution should be future-proofed so that
the fragment's onActivityResult doesn't get called twice.

I would like to propose the following modified solution proposed by LEO.

In the Fragment's parent Activity implementation:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    boolean handled = false;

    // The following is a hack to ensure that the InAppPurchasesFragment receives
    // its onActivityResult call.
    //
    // For more information on this issue, read here:
    //
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131171/calling-startintentsenderforresult-from-fragment-android-billing-v3
    //
    // Note: If Google ever fixes the issue with startIntentSenderForResult() and
    // starts forwarding on the onActivityResult to the fragment automatically, we
    // should future-proof this code so it will still work.
    //
    // If we don't do anything and always call super.onActivityResult, we risk 
    // having the billing fragment's onActivityResult called more than once for
    // the same result.
    //
    // To accomplish this, we create a method called checkIabHelperHandleActivityResult
    // in the billing fragment that returns a boolean indicating whether the result was 
    // handled or not.  We would just call Fragment's onActivityResult method, except 
    // its return value is void.
    //
    // Then call this new method in the billing fragment here and only call 
    // super.onActivityResult if the billing fragment didn't handle it.

    if (inAppPurchasesFragment != null)
    {
        handled = inAppPurchasesFragment.checkIabHelperHandleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    if (!handled)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Then in your IAB Fragment's implementation:

```
/**
 * Allow the IabHelper to process an onActivityResult if it can
 * 
 * @param requestCode The request code
 * @param resultCode The result code
 * @param data The data
 * 
 * @return true if the IABHelper handled the result, else false
 */

public boolean checkIabHelperHandleActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    return (iabHelper != null) && iabHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (!checkIabHelperHandleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest creating some sort of generic handling of this issue in your base activity class if you have access to it.

For example:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    private List<ActivityResultHandler> mResultHandlers 
        = new ArrayList<ActivityResultHandler>();

    public void registerActivityResultHandler(ActivityResultHandler resultHandler) {
        mResultHandlers.add(resultHandler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        for (ActivityResultHandler resultHandler : mResultHandlers) {
            resultHandler.handle();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll need to implement ActivityResultHandler interface by your fragments and register them on activity startup.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` now contains a backwards compatible version of `startIntentSenderForResult()`, so this answer is obsolete.

**Old answer:**

As of support library 23.2.0, modifying the `requestCode` no longer works: `FragmentActivity` now keeps track of the requests made by its fragments. I added this method to the `FragmentActivity` that was hosting the `Fragment` (code based on `FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(Fragment, Intent, int, Bundle)`):

```
public void startIntentSenderFromFragment(Fragment fragment, IntentSender intent, int requestCode, @Nullable Intent fillInIntent, int flagsMask, int flagsValues, int extraFlags) throws IntentSender.SendIntentException {
    if (requestCode == -1) {
        startIntentSenderForResult(intent, requestCode, fillInIntent, flagsMask, flagsValues, extraFlags);
        return;
    }

    if ((requestCode & 0xffff0000) != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode");
    }

    try {
        Method method = FragmentActivity.class.getDeclaredMethod("allocateRequestIndex", Fragment.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        int requestIndex = (int) method.invoke(this, fragment);
        startIntentSenderForResult(intent, ((requestIndex + 1) << 16) + (requestCode & 0xffff), fillInIntent, flagsMask, flagsValues, extraFlags);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

When calling this, only the passed `Fragment` will receive the  `onActivityResult()` call.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass fragment and data to parent activity, then call the fragment from onActivityResult in parent activity.

like this

in fragment:

```html
HomeActivity activity = (HomeActivity) getActivity();
activity.purchaseLauncher(this, mHelper, productDTO.getSku(), RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, PAYLOAD);
```

in parent activity:

```html
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (storeFragment != null) {
            storeFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    public void purchaseLauncher(StoreFragment storeFragment, IabHelper mHelper, String sku, int requestCode, IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener, String payload) {
        this.storeFragment = storeFragment;
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, sku, requestCode, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (requestCode == RC_REQUEST) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(ContainerAvtivity.this,ContainerAvtivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

`RC_REQUEST` is same as you used to launch purchase flow

Add this in the `onActivityResult` of your Activity.The inventory listener will produce the desired result for you.(I know its a temp fix but worked for me)).

Answer (score 0):

In my case i did onActivityResult in Activity :

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }

}
```

and same in fragment and it makes in app billing works

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    }
    else {
        Log.d(ITEM_SKU, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get callback on your fragment than call `super.onActivityResult()` from your activity.

This will call your fragments `onActivityResult()`.

And don't forget to call `startIntentSenderForResult` from your fragment context.

Don't use activity context `getActivity().startIntentSenderForResult`

Answer (score -1):

You need to call

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

at the beginning of your Activity's and Fragment's onActivityResult to cascade the Results to the fragments.

In my FragmentActivity this reads as

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // No action here, call super to delegate to Fragments
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: The problem is `startIntentSenderForResult()` does not forward the result to the fragment that called it; only the activity's `onActivityResult()` is called because the request code is not masked like it is when `Fragment.startActivityForResult()` is called.