# onIabPurchaseFinished never called.

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I've been trying to set up in-app billing for my first app, and have been using the android.test.purchased sku. The purchase come through, and I manage to get the SKU into my inventory, but, as the title says, onIabPurchaseFinished, is never called.

I think it may have something to do with this Log: "Couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@406743d0 has no id". That pops up, right before going of to Google Play. I'm not really sure what that means though...

Launching purchase:

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, sku, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "");
```

And the Listener:

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase info) {
        System.out.println("Purchase Finish heard something");

        if (result.isFailure()) {
             Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);
             return;
        } else{
                Log.d(TAG,"Success!");
             }


    }
};
```

Comment: I should maybe add that I am trying to do this from within a tab

Comment: I've set the id programmatically, but no difference.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Try adding this to the Activity that calls `mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(..)`:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);

    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }
}
```

Comment: had the same issue and that worked perfect. But what i want to know is why doesnt the call back get executed like one would assume, why do we have to make the call to that our self? Kind of makes the callback useless :/

Comment: Also helped me, thx.  @Spider, the reason you need this method in your Activity is that otherwise mHelper's handleActivityResult() method won't get called.  In other words, this is the real/standard handleActivityResult() needed in the Activity, and mHelper's is actually just a regular old method.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's a bug in the documentation (they never mention needing this or in IabHelper.

IabHelper's launchPurchaseFlow() invokes the startIntentSenderForResult - which will call your activity's onActivityResult() when it's finished.

Comment: BTW, if you have a payment fragment like I do, where you do all of the callbacks in the fragment's Java, this solution works. Just create a public fragment object and use that to refer to the iabhelper, i.e. paymentFragment.mHelper.HandleActivity...

Comment: I thought I had solved my problem when I found this... then I realized I had already implemented this function and it still doesn't work... *sigh*

Comment: I want to consume the purchase i ihave made. But i am never get call back to the onPurchase finished. How can i make Asynconsume from onActivityResult

Comment: Note that overriding onActivityResult() on a Fragment doesn't work, it must be done on an Activity

Comment: @cprcrack Correct, the activityResult is called on the owning activity. This solution, combined with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131171/calling-startintentsenderforresult-from-fragment-android-billing-v3  worked for me to get around that.

Comment: Thanks so much but honestly can you please tell us how the heck you got to that solution?

Comment: It is documented but at wrong place. IabHelper's handleActivityResult() method JavaDoc is having mention about it. It says...
     * Handles an activity result that's part of the purchase flow in in-app billing. If you are calling {@link #launchPurchaseFlow}, then you must call this method from your Activity's {@link android.app.Activity@onActivityResult} method. This method MUST be called from the UI thread of the Activity.

Answer (score 8):

i just found out another important thing: the requestCode that is used to launch the purchase flow has to be >= 0!

i used "new Random().nextInt()" to generate a random requestCode, and sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't. now i found out in the following documentation, that the requestCode should not be a negative number:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and the **onActivityResult** was not called either.

 Inspired from [@Ghulam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48599182/2317116) I realized that the activity **onActivityResult** doesn't call the fragment's **onActivityResult** automatically so I had to do it 
manually.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(mCurrentFragment!= null){
            mCurrentFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In my case, this answer worked, but I had to add an OnActivityResult override in my main activity ( https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB/issues/166 )

Answer (score 1):

You need to call protected void onActivityResult(); In your parent Activity instead of MainActivity(Trivial Drive) where from you are calling your MainActivity that is Trivial Drive Activity.

you will receive resultcode values -1 if purchase successful otherwise 0.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and the accepted solution was already implemented but couldn't tell what was causing this. Moving to the new **Google Play Billing Library 1.0** *(released on 19 September 2017)* fixed the issue for me!

I hope following links will help someone who would like to implement the new library:

[Google's blog post about the release](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/google-play-billing-library-10-released.html)

[Google's youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y78ugwN4Obg)

[Play Billing Library Training Class](https://developer.android.com/training/play-billing-library/index.html)

[Google's Trivial Drive v2 Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive_v2)

[Play Billing Library codelab published during Google I/O 2017](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/play-billing-codelab/#0)

[Play Billing Library Docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html)

[Official reference for classes and methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/classes.html)

[Releases notes](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_releases_notes.html)