# Android: In App purchase - onIabPurchaseFinished not called and handleActivityResult returning false

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, onactivityresult

I want to do in app billing from my app.

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener purchaseThisAppListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchaseDetails) {             
            if(result.isFailure()) {
                if(result.getResponse() == IabHelper.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
                    String toastText = "Item is already purchased.\nRestoring purchase.";
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());;
                    prefs.edit().putBoolean("isAppPurchased", true).commit();
                    myActivity.refresh_status = myActivity.REFRESH_ACTIVITY;

                    Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(thisActivityContext);
                    alert.setTitle("Item already owned");
                    alert.setMessage("You already own this item. Restoring purchase.");
                    alert.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
                    alert.show();   


                    for(int i = 3; i < myUtility.isCategoryAvailable.length; i++) {
                        myUtility.isCategoryAvailable[i] = true;                
                    }
                    myUtility.isAllCategoriesAvailable = true;
                    isAppPurchased = true;
                }

                return;
            }
            else if (purchaseDetails.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {    
                prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

                if(prefs != null) {
                    prefs.edit().putBoolean(IS_APP_PURCHASED, true).commit();
                    for(int i = 3; i < myUtility.isCategoryAvailable.length; i++) {
                        myUtility.isCategoryAvailable[i] = true;                
                    }
                    myUtility.isAllCategoriesAvailable = true;
                    isAppPurchased = true;

                }
                else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Preferences not found");
                }

            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Purchase successful, but different Item SKU found");
            }

        }

    };
```

I also added onActivityResult as I read that the above function is not called. 
[onIabPurchaseFinished never called.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800286/oniabpurchasefinished-never-called)

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            Log.d("IN APP ACTIVITY", "ENTERED");


        }
        else {
            Log.d("IN APP ACTIVITY", "DID NOT ENTER");

        }

    }
```

All this is working when I put ITEM_SKU = "android.test.purchased";
But, when I publish this app on GooglePlay, **!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)** always returns false. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to still be a problem with using the static SKU "android.test.purchased" it seems like you're running into a similar problem as outlined in this question: [Android in app purchase: Signature verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600664/android-in-app-purchase-signature-verification-failed)

I had this problem as well, but once I used my own SKU everything worked fine. I think the best way to move forward would be to setup an In-App Product in the developer console as outlined here: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html and then test using that and testing accounts (which you can also setup in the console - navigate to settings, account details and scroll down till you see *Gmail accounts with testing access*) so you don't get charged. It's a bit tedious but it worked for me.