# IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener not calling in In-app purchase subscription v3

Tags: android, android-fragments, in-app-purchase, fragment, in-app-billing

I am trying to get back to the IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener when purchasing is over for my subscription , but the problem is Its not calling when purchase is done .

I had tried with onactivity result but still its not working 
here Is my code block
I'm extending fragments as below

```
public class ConfirmationScreen extends Fragment {

mHelper = new IabHelper(getActivity(), base64EncodedPublicKey);
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
           // Oh noes, there was a problem.
           complain("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
           return;
        }

        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        // IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
        Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
        //  mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
    }
});

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        // Is it a failure?
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

        /*
         * Check for items we own. Notice that for each purchase, we check
         * the developer payload to see if it's correct! See
         * verifyDeveloperPayload().
         */

        Purchase gasPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU);
        if (gasPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(gasPurchase)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "We have gas. Consuming it.");
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU), mConsumeFinishedListener);
            return;
        }
    }
};

//Callback for when a purchase is finished
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);
        // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;
        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");
        if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU)) {
            //bought 1/4 tank of gas. So consume it.
            Log.d(TAG, "Purchase is gas. Starting gas consumption.");
        }
    }
};
```

I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800286/oniabpurchasefinished-never-called) link

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement the `onActivityResult` method on your `FragmentActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you need to override it on the main activity

Answer (score 0):

> You need to implement the onActivityResult method on your FragmentActivity

This has to be put in activity, which actually runs the:

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(...);
```