# Should I use intents or listeners?

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

**TL;DR: According to the documentation there are two different ways to purchase a product, which do I use? Do I use an intent or `IABHelper.launchPurchaseFlow()`?**

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html) documentation, use `launchPurchaseFlow();` and attached listener to make a purchase:

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = 
    new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase)
        {
            //Item bought...? Why should I use this option
        }
};

mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_GAS, 10001,
       mPurchaseFinishedListener, "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
```

However, according to [this](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) documentation, I must use intents and `onActivityForResult()` to purchase a product:

```
startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
       1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
       Integer.valueOf(0));
```

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1001) {      
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Item bought...? Why should I use this option
        }
    }
}
```

Which method should I use to purchase the product? Both options seem extremely similar, but what is the difference, and is one better?

Comment: This entirely depends on where you want the code to flow to. Both are perfectly valid.

Comment: Both are actually valid, it is mostly depends on preference.. I sometimes use listeners on `Adapter` which is not in the same class as the `Fragment` so that I don't pass the `Fragment` into the `Adapter`

Comment: @cricket_007 Could you provide me with a scenario where I may want to use one option over the other? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Simply put: If you want to load some data in the current activity's context -- Use the listener. If you want to load that data in a different activity -- use the Intent. That's the main reason I can think of, at the moment.

Comment: @cricket_007 So I can do `startIntentSenderForResult()` in one activity, change activities, and load the data from another activity using `onActivityResult()`, right?

Comment: Essentially, that method *"Launches an activity for which you would like a result when it finished. When this activity exits, your onActivityResult() method will be called with the given requestCode"* -- meaning you need to first finish the current activity. The listener, on the otherhand will execute when the request is complete.

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen What do you mean by serving different phases? Don't they achieve the same thing at the end? Please let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a mistake. You can follow either tutorial. However, I think IabHelper is quite convenient because it is in Android sample code with lots of exception message that you can quickly replace with yours.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. If I do use the listener however, IabHelper's launchPurchaseFlow() uses startIntentSenderForResult anyway which calls onActivityResult() when it's finished. So even if I use the listener, I need the onActivityForResult, which they don't mention in the documentation. This link clears that up a bit:

[onIabPurchaseFinished never called.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800286/oniabpurchasefinished-never-called)