# In app billing consumable item

Tags: android, android-studio, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am trying to implement Google In-App Billing for selling consumable items (coins). I tested it with a non-consumable item and it worked fine. But I can't make it consumable. Every time I test it, I can only buy it once !
Here is my code :

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    IabHelper mHelper;

```
boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
    String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();

/*
 * TODO: verify that the developer payload of the purchase is correct. It will be
 * the same one that you sent when initiating the purchase.
 *
 * WARNING: Locally generating a random string when starting a purchase and
 * verifying it here might seem like a good approach, but this will fail in the
 * case where the user purchases an item on one device and then uses your app on
 * a different device, because on the other device you will not have access to the
 * random string you originally generated.
 *
 * So a good developer payload has these characteristics:
 *
 * 1. If two different users purchase an item, the payload is different between them,
 *    so that one user's purchase can't be replayed to another user.
 *
 * 2. The payload must be such that you can verify it even when the app wasn't the
 *    one who initiated the purchase flow (so that items purchased by the user on
 *    one device work on other devices owned by the user).
 *
 * Using your own server to store and verify developer payloads across app
 * installations is recommended.
 */

    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String base64EncodedPublicKey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlJQQTbdM6zP0585Ar0YKZAYQish29+AkZpdu4fGUO3WLoVm9UPOSNMMBmo8odzQbcVZdlKUfocohg/52qoQk9crVIhdHJM+O1GK9+hJSdVkZo0PWW5+1sJSCQ7cw0NTxIdDQVSYT0WWC2zkn8Fpxyz1N9pGHh21jxbviDYcnh1gyK+mCLt6jWcVxKl8BYgC0SS7K9F+7kHy+B/GG8ZSl2xhcCqlid/8cEjqH7yvMPciWA8lHvHB7rGz/nUg/v2ydhmUY6f8Ifh6+ygUu2XrhDU0v8wZ24yKw2Kw4SVZbm5ZmC/DXCgx+hIWVL+/yAFqHJ0ygqwW4aLTuKV6PyDaC1QIDAQAB";

    // compute your public key and store it in base64EncodedPublicKey
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh no, there was a problem.
                Log.d("TAG", "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
                Log.i("TAG", "ERROR");
            }
            // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
            //check owned items & consum em
            checkOwnedItems();
            //make a test purchase
                makePurchase();
        }
    });

}

private void makePurchase() {
    try {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, "next", 10001,
                mPurchaseFinishedListener, "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
    } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        showToast("oh no error purchase" + String.valueOf(e));
    }
}

private void checkOwnedItems() {
    try {
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
    } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
        showToast("Oh no error in check()");
        //complain("Error querying inventory. Another async operation in progress.");
    }
}


// Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and subscriptions we own
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Purchase item = inventory.getPurchase("next");
        if (item != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(item)) {
            //Log.d("TAG", "We have gas. Consuming it.");
            try {
                mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase("next"), mConsumeFinishedListener);
            } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
                // complain("Error consuming gas. Another async operation in progress.");
                showToast("oh no error when consuming");
            }
            return;
        }
    }

};


// Called when consumption is complete
IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Consumption finished. Purchase: " + purchase + ", result: " + result);

        // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        // We know this is the "gas" sku because it's the only one we consume,
        // so we don't check which sku was consumed. If you have more than one
        // sku, you probably should check...
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // successfully consumed, so we apply the effects of the item in our
            // game world's logic, which in our case means filling the gas tank a bit
            //Log.d(TAG, "Consumption successful. Provisioning.");
            //mTank = mTank == TANK_MAX ? TANK_MAX : mTank + 1;
            // saveData();
            // alert("You filled 1/4 tank. Your tank is now " + String.valueOf(mTank) + "/4 full!");
        }
        else {
            //complain("Error while consuming: " + result);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", "End consumption flow.");
    }
};


// Callback for when a purchase is finished
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);

        // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // complain("Error purchasing: " + result);
            return;
        }
        if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
            // complain("Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
            return;
        }

        Log.d("TAG", "Purchase successful.");

        if (purchase.getSku().equals("next")) {

            Log.d("TAG", "Purchase is gas. Starting gas consumption.");
            try {
                mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
            } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
                //complain("Error consuming gas. Another async operation in progress.");
                showToast("oh no error when consuming");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null) try {
        mHelper.dispose();
    } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mHelper = null;
}
private void showToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}
}

Sorry for my english and thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're consuming your items successfully? Are you sure you're not getting exceptions? For example, `checkOwnedItems()` and `mHelper.consumeAsync()` in `mGotInventoryListener` both have empty catch blocks (bad practice btw), hence the issue might be hidden from you...

Comment: yes you right I'll make a toast if success or fail. (It was 2 in the morning and I just forgot that ;)

Comment: What's the exception? (BTW have you added e.printStackTrace() in those catch blocks? (I don't see it updated in the code above)

Comment: ok so the purchase throws the error :can't start async operation (launchPurchaseFlow) because another async operation (refresh inventory) is in progress. But how do I know when this is finished

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it now : So my first problem was that I called makePurchase right after the checkOwnedItems method --> Throws Exception :can't start async operation (launchPurchaseFlow) because another async operation (refresh inventory) is in progress.Then I used a button to call makePurchase and it still wasn't working... because I had made toasts with success or fail + exception in all listeners I knew that the onIabPurchaseFinished method wasn't called so I googled and found this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14968203/4106137.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having trouble using the native in-app billing system, but then I found [this library](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer I ll check it out.

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong but it still doesn't work : it makes a toast with onBillingInitialized but then nothing happens (I pasted the code wich was in the project in onClick : case : consume-button in the onCreate method...)

Comment: Are you expecting to see the google play dialog to actual buy something?

Comment: yes (I have a test account and the non-consumable item worked fine)

Comment: to test if it actually works you need to publish the app, you can publish in closed beta, and ask a friend to test it

Comment: yeas I already did that (but I just made a tester google account by myself) and it worked I just have trouble making the item consumable

Comment: When you create items in the Google console, you can either create a consumable item or a subscription